# PHP - Using a for loop instead of a switch statement

Tags: php, loops, dynamic, for-loop, switch-statement

Overflow community first post ever!

Currently i'm working on a project and have started to use PHP to dynamic insert pages.

At this point in time I have...

```
switch ($route) {
  case 'step1':
        include('./views/enrolment/mainstream/_step1.php');
        include('./views/partials/_footer.php') ;
        break;
    case 'step2':
        include('./views/enrolment/mainstream/_step2.php');
        include('./views/partials/_footer.php') ;
        break;
    case 'step3':
        include('./views/enrolment/mainstream/_step3.php');
        include('./views/partials/_footer.php');
        break;
    case 'step4':
        include('./views/enrolment/mainstream/_step4.php');
        include('./views/partials/_footer.php');
        break;
    case 'step5':
        include('./views/enrolment/mainstream/_step5.php');
        include('./views/partials/_footer.php');
        break;
    case 'step6':
        include('./views/enrolment/mainstream/_step6.php');
        include('./views/partials/_footer.php');
        break;
    case 'step7':
        include('./views/enrolment/mainstream/_step7.php');
        include('./views/partials/_footer.php');
        break;
```

This to means seems horrifically long and is better achieved through a for loop, however i'm a newbie to PHP and am entirely unsure of how I would go about implementing this idea.

Any other sugguestions without a the use of a for loop is also welcome!

Thanks guys!

Comment: The only difference between each step is the number in "stepX"? Then... have you heard of ***variables***?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if that file exists using php's file_exists() fn

```
if(file_exists('./views/enrolment/mainstream/_'.$routes.'.php')) {
    include('./views/enrolment/mainstream/_'.$routes.'.php');
    include('./views/partials/_footer.php') ;
}
```

Handle the else part to suit your need.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant answers people and so fast! All your answers worked equally and as effectively as one another! But i had to choose one, thank you all in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this easy solution is good for you:

```
include('./views/enrolment/mainstream/_'.$route.'.php');
include('./views/partials/_footer.php');
```

Comment: A copy&paste answer? LOL

Answer (score 0):

To reduce your code considerably:

```
include('./views/enrolment/mainstream/_step' . $route . '.php');
include('./views/partials/_footer.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont use `$route` as variable to load file?

```
include("./views/enrolment/mainstream/_{$route}.php");
include('./views/partials/_footer.php') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like @praveen said use:

```
include('./views/enrolment/mainstream/_'.$routes.'.php');
```

However you are duplicating:

```
include('./views/partials/_footer.php');
```

for each query, why not just have that in the page as static?

Answer (score 0):

it is better to check the `$route` value

```
if (in_array($route, range(1, 7))){
    include('./views/enrolment/mainstream/_'.$route.'.php');
    include('./views/partials/_footer.php') ;
} else {
    //...error code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
$i = 1;
$steps = 7;

for($i = 1; $i <= $steps; $i++) {
  if($route === 'step' . $i) {
     include('./views/enrolment/mainstream/_step' . $i . '.php');
     include('./views/partials/_footer.php');
     break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the title of the question is not so right, he will not need a for to do what he want, so this code isn't needed, because you will check 7 times `if($route === 'step' . $i) {`

Answer (score -1):

```
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
    if($route == "step" . $i){
        include('./views/enrolment/mainstream/_step' .$i . '.php');
        include('./views/partials/_footer.php');
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the title of the question is not so right, he will not need a for to do what he want, so this code isn't needed, because you will check 7 times `if($route === 'step' . $i) {`